# Is there an obvious n-dimensional elasticity complex?

Tags: finite-element

Finite element exterior calculus helps to furnish nice stable elements for many common elliptic PDE by looking at the de Rham complex

$$\Lambda^0(\Omega) \stackrel{d_1}{\to} \Lambda^1(\Omega) \stackrel{d_2}{\to} \ldots \stackrel{d_n}{\to} \Lambda^n(\Omega)$$

where $\Lambda^k(\Omega)$ are the $k$-forms on the domain $\Omega$ and $d_k$ is the exterior derivative.
For example the mixed form of the Poisson equation and various other vector Laplace equations are nicely described by other parts of the sequence.
Moreover, the de Rham complex is relatively easy to describe in arbitrary dimensions, not just $n = 2$ or 3.

There are also chain complexes that describe the elasticity equations in dimensions 2 or 3.
For example, in dimension 2, we can use the sequence

$$\phi \mapsto \partial_k\partial_k\phi\cdot\delta_{ij} - \partial_i\partial_j\phi,$$
$$\sigma_{ij} \mapsto \partial_j\sigma_{ij}.$$

The composition of these two maps is zero so it's a perfectly nice complex.
There's a similar generalization to 3D.
**What, if any, is the natural generalization of the elasticity complex to arbitrary dimensions?**
I've only ever seen it described specifically for dimensions 2 or 3.